# Date format Wikimedia

Tags: date, mediawiki, persian

I have a wiki in persian. In my preferences (user preferences), I can change date format for persian. And, I can see that the date format is as follow:

[image]

This picture shows that the user date format is correct and in persian, which is correct.

But when I have signed out, The date format of site is not persian. It looks like this:

[image]

This picture shows that the default date format is not persian, which is not the case I want to be.

I want the default date format of the site be in persian, too.
It would be great if some one guide me how to change the default time zone and date format of the wiki site.

Wiki Site Address: wiki.aicd.ir

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer as follow:

Add the following code at the end of LocalSettings.php file to change the default date format to 'persian':

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['date'] = 'persian';
```

[Wiki Site to Check](http://wiki.aicd.ir)